# How Invalidate Riverpod provider in a widget ,not on WillPopScope

Tags: riverpod

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    ref.invalidate(textProvider);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Column(
      children: [MyTodoListWidget()],
    );
  }
}

class MyTodoWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyTodoListWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final text = ref.watch(textProvider);
    return Text(text);
  }
}

final textProvider = StateProvider((ref) => '');
```

Here i am initializing provider in

```
MyTodoWidget
```

and dispose this in

```
MyApp
```

getting this type of error :

'To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.'